# How to disable the keyboard shortcut for inverse video on ubuntu gnome (metacity)?

Tags: ubuntu, metacity

This doesn't appear to be an option in the normal program for editing keyboard shortcuts, but it is stealing one of my favorite emacs bindings.  Might be somehow related to Metacity instead of being a general gnome setting.  I know this can be fixed because I figured out how to do it at one point, but now I can't remember how.  Currently set to <kbd>Window</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>.

Comment: Are you sure you are running Metacity? This looks like Compiz to me (I've never seen this feature in metacity but I could be wrong). You can try installing compizconfig-settings-manager, and disabling / editing the "Negative" plugin shortcut.

Comment: As he's a new member, it would be nice to give Nicolas the opportunity to answer himself and mark his answer as accepted. This will give you both reputation points.

Comment: @slhck - Thanks for the etiquette pointer, if Nicolas would like to provide an answer, I'll be happy to delete mine and mark his as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Nicolas in his comment, I am indeed running Compiz instead of Metacity.  He is also correct in that installing compizconfig-settings-manager and disabling the "Negative" plugin shortcut has solved my problem.  What a painful way to track down random keybindings installed at the system level...